# How do 2 players trade Pokemon in Heartgold / Soulsilver

Tags: pokemon-fourth-generation

How can 2 players, 1 with Heart Gold and 1 with Soul Silver trade Pokemon with each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of you need to have Wifi communications enabled in your DS. This should always be the case if you have an old DS or a DS Lite, but the DSi offers options to disable it.

Once you have done so, go upstairs in any Pokemon Center, and talk to the person behind one of the counters, and follow the instructions. You should be dropped into a room where you can see other players who are also connected over wifi. Talk to another player to trade with them.

Answer (score 3):

Via Pokemon Centers. There should be a counter asking to communicate with another player to trade and battle.

Comment: And how does it work?  Do we need to have Wifi enabled or can we just be near each other?

Comment: Well, you would have to be near each other and use a friends room or something, because as of now, the Pokemon wifi connection has ceased to work.

Comment: Does the game need to be beaten for this to work?  OR can I do it right after the first gym?

Comment: The game does not have to be beaten for this to work. At any time in any point of the game (after certain requirements like the one you stated) you can access the trading rooms. But the best advice to give is to trade only when you have enough pokemon (about 6)

Comment: Why is it best to trade 6 Pokemon?  My idea here is to just use one game to get all the starters then trade them to the other game.

Comment: I might have written it in a way you might not understand, but what I meant is that when you want to trade with other users, bringing the maximum amount of Pokemon you can bring increases trading rates. Sorry for any misunderstanding. @Mkalafut

Comment: OHH wait. Now I understand. You don't have to beat the game each time. Once you have access to trading, you could proceed with the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. With your friend in the same room or home. Go to the Pokemon Center. Go upstairs (not downstairs) and talk to the lady in the middle. She will bring you to a union room. There you can trade and battle. You can do this without a wifi connection.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Arqade! While your answer is correct, the all caps is a bit much. In the future, please refrain from doing that. Enjoy your time here at Arqade!